# Solar power with battery backup circuit

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, battery-charging, circuit-design, solar-cell

I am building a project with the goal of having on-board electronics (ESC, motor, receiver, etc.) get power from solar cells when there is enough sunlight, and get power from both solar and battery when there is not enough sunlight. Additionally, if there is excess power from solar, the extra power should trickle charge the battery, since the battery and solar cells are connected in parallel and the energy flow is decided by Kirchhoff’s current law. A receiver-controlled switch will be used to connect/disconnect the solar cells depending on need.

Below I have attached the circuit I designed and the questions I have about it.

[image: block diagram of design]

My questions regarding the circuit design are the following:

1. How can overcharging the battery be avoided?
2. <strike>I am thinking that an MPPT is not needed since the battery and solar panels are well adjusted in parallel. Is this a good idea to not have a MPPT because of that and because a MPPT is a heavy device with some power dissipation?</strike>
3. <strike>Is the Schottky diode necessary in the setup (since the solar cells themselves act as a diode and would only be damaged if there is much higher voltage)?</strike>
4. Would my current setup achieve my goal?
5. Do you have any other recommendations?
6. Is there any small electronic device that I can add that will help me monitor the voltage of battery from a far away distance?
7. I think that Li-po balancing is not an issue since the Li-po will not be too deeply discharged or with high current. Is my thinking correct, and if not, how would the battery be balanced while charging through solar?

Comment: You cannot *renumber* the questions *after* you've received any answers which use the "old" numbers, because that changes the meaning of those answers. Instead I've added your new questions, with new numbers, and removed questions which you no longer want, by using HTML "strikethrough".

Comment: Thank you sir. Sorry I am a bit new to this and didn't look at it.

Comment: krishna - You edited the question to remove all the points you asked. That is effectively vandalism and is not allowed. You received an answer to your original 4 questions. Part of the purpose of Stack Exchange is to collect Q&A which may be useful to other people in the future. Effectively removing all value from the question, as you did, goes against that. Therefore your edit has been reversed.

Answer (score 1):

1. It cannot.
2. wrong MPPT will improve efficiency and regulate Vbat charge CC, CV and cutoff if you buy the right one.
3. Wrong , diode is necessary
4. No it won’t work . Look harder for solutions